# How to realize foreign relationship between datagridviews in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, foreign-keys

I am new to C# and I need to make a project (Price lists for Clients).

My question is:

How to on button click (Show Price List) for selected Client in Row of Datagrid (ClientID is primary key here), open a new form with a new Datagrid in which display his prices (only for selected client); Also in this Datagrid is column ServiceID.
So, ServiceID and ClientsID are foreign keys. I created this three tables in SQL MS, and their foreign relationships.
I have limitations for the task, I can’t use MVC either Entity Framework.

I just need help about code in C#

Comment: This sounds like homework...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.